# Why I take NA as matrix multiplication output?

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication, missing-data

I have two matrix, one is like below (1*10):

```
x <- (1,-0.00247043,-0.002320707,-0.002170984,-0.003518491,-0.002695014,-0.001871538,-0.002395568,-0.003069322,-0.003817937)
```

and the second one is like (10 * 1):

```
y <- (6.911842e-06,-6.940286e-06,-3.648303e-06,3.664410e-07,-4.102516e-07,-3.479830e-06,-5.308621e-06,-3.571418e-06,-4.058502e-06,-4.058502e-06)
```

So my code for multiplication is like:

```
res <- x %*% y
```

but it returns NA as the result, could you please guide me?

Comment: No it does not return `NA`.

Comment: you are missing the `c` in  your vector assignement. res gives: 6.993923e-06.

Comment: @Onyambu and @TarJae, I have just put here a part of my data, and I have just found I also have `NA` in my data. Maybe I got NA for this. Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the NA's? Do you need to remove them, (recall, if you remove an NA in x, you will have to remove the corresponding value in y whether its NA or not),, Do you want to replace the NA with 0 or 1? Replaceing by 0 is the same as removing the NA.

Comment: NA times anything is NA. NA in any call to sum is NA.  Were you expecting R to make up a value to replace the NA?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the function `c()`, try:

```
    x <- c(1,-0.00247043,-0.002320707,-0.002170984,-0.003518491,-0.002695014,-0.001871538,-0.002395568,-0.003069322,-0.003817937)
    y <- c(6.911842e-06,-6.940286e-06,-3.648303e-06,3.664410e-07,-4.102516e-07,-3.479830e-06,-5.308621e-06,-3.571418e-06,-4.058502e-06,-4.058502e-06)
    
    matrix(x,nrow = 1) %*% matrix(y,nrow = 10)
             [,1]
[1,] 6.993923e-06

    x %*% y
             [,1]
[1,] 6.993923e-06
```

Comment: No, infact both x and y are matrix, I mean I wrote them as `as.matrix(x)`, and the second one is `y <- cov(t(my_data_frame))`. I just wrote sample numbers here. The other point, I have just noticed is that I have `NA` in the values. Does it have effect on the result?